# Recognize WCF solution

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asmx

I am new in Web Service Developement in .NET. Now I am analyzing a big solution of dozens of projects. There I have project that uses a web service and I want to know if it is a **WCF Service** or some other kind like **Web API**...
In the past I used **ASMX** Web Services in .NET and you were able to recognize a **ASMX** web service via its file extension. But here I don't see any special extensions in the project. I have read that WCF Services have .svc files if they are hosted in IIS. But this project doesn't have a .svc file. So, what are the main characteristics which distinguish a WCF Service from other web services in .NET.
The structure of the solution is as following:

```
-Solution  
  +-CreateDocWebServiceInterface  
  +-CreateDocWebService
  +-...
```

The `CreateDocWebServiceInterface` looks like that:

```
namespace CreateDocWebServiceInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract(Name = "ICreateDocWebService", Namespace = "http://www.standardlife.de/CreateDocWebService")]
    [RequiredParametersBehavior]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bookmark))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<Bookmark>))]
    public interface ICreateDocWebService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        byte[] CreateDoc(OutputFormat OutputFormat, bool DuplexPrinting, List<Document> Documents);        
    }
}
```

And the `CreateDocWebService` looks like that:

```
namespace CreateDocWebService
{
    // single threaded, but each request is handled concurrent !
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, Namespace = "http://www.blablabla.de/CreateDocWebService")]
    public class CreateDocWebService : ICreateDocWebService
    {
        public byte[] CreateDoc(OutputFormat outputFormat, bool duplexPrinting, List<Document> documents)
        {
            bla bla bla
        }
    }
}
```

It could be a Web Service with **Web API**, but as I know Web API web services consist of **controllers** which derive from the `ApiController`?!(Is this correct and the unique characteristic of Web Api Web Services?)
So is this a WCF Service? And what is the unique characteristic of a WCF service and of an Web API Web Service

Comment: mmm it looks like a WCF ... not  a WebAPI ... caus eit has a Interface to make a contract with other who want to use this WS .. and it use a NameSpace (usually namesapces are for XML ..so for SOAP . so for WCF)

Comment: It is WCF Service, check the detail suggestion on [Recognize WCF solution][1]


  [1]: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b8bb3a8c-f588-4b8a-b62f-e7b22af21935/recognize-wcf-solution?forum=wcf

Answer (score 1):

It is a WCF Project because your Interface is surrounded by `[ServiceContract]`.

Another way if you want to know if it's a WCF Project or ASP.NET Web Service simply open your project's folders in File Explorer. You can hover over the icon with your mouse and a tooltip will display the project type as shown in the picture. Also, you can look under the **Type** column in File Explorer and it shows it there as well.

WCF Web Service Project:
[image: WCF Web Service]

ASP.NET Web Service Project:
[image]

Also to note, if your project has a Resources.Designer.cs or Settings.Designer.cs in its **Properties** folder it's likely a WinForms application.